# how to find out account or usage infos for a docker image?

Tags: docker

How can i find out in detail how to use the service that an image provides? So far, i found no documentation for images that `docker search` returns, except the short image description string.

The only way i found so far is to study the corresponding Dockerfile, but what if i can't find it? For example, i run `docker run -d -P -v data:/var/lib/mysql mysql` and want to know the mysql root account of the image. I tried `docker inspect` but that gave no hints. Do i have to inspect all commits to understand what files changed?

If `docker search` returns many images, how do you find out which one fits best?

Answer (score 0):

Search images at docker-hub (https://registry.hub.docker.com), not at command line (`docker search`). Docker-hub search results include additional infos about usage and build process.